# What is the output of the following code?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int x=5,y=10,z=15;
  printf("%d %d %d");
  return 0;
}
```

Output: 15 10 5  //In Turbo C 4.5

```
    3 Garbage values in gcc compiler
```

My teacher told me when we define the variables like int x=5,y=10,z=15; they are by default taken as auto type and stored in stack.When you try print 3 integer values without using their names by printf(), it will print those 3 values in LIFO format as Turbo C compiler does.
But what I think when we define 3 integer variables, they may not be stored in continuous memory locations.So when I try to print 3 integer values without using their names, the compiler will print any three values from top of the stack.so the output will come 3 garbage values as in gcc..

Comment: So, your question is...?

Comment: Get a new teacher.  If he is saying anything other than "this is undefined behaviour, don't do it" he doesn't know what he is talking about.

Comment: @Daniel Standage    what is logically correct ?

Comment: @JeremyP I completely disagree (on the "Get a new teacher" part, not the "undefined behavior" part). Writing a few undefined programs and seeing them behave erratically can be part of a good C course and does not mean the students are encouraged to use undefined constructs in their programs. And I could never learn anything from teachers who offered only dogma without illustration nor explanation. In any case, the question does not say that the teacher encouraged students to write `printf("%d %d %d");`.

Comment: @Pascal agree. If your teacher will avoid these cases, it would be much more difficult to find such a bug in code. read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html for longer version :)

Comment: Your teacher is wrong to cover edges cases weirdnesses like how variables might get allocated in particular compilers before covering real things like how to use printf properly. I don't actually care how any compiler does this, and I wouldn't raise the subject with unsuspecting undergrads. I would use the time to teach the language and idioms, which are complex enough without getting into per-compiler variations that can be safely ignored by people writing sensible code (in this case sensible meaning as many subsequent arguments to printf as there were placeholders in the format string.)

Comment: Weather or not the teacher should bring this type of thing up depends on what they are trying to teach. As can be seen by many questions on SO people learning C are going to write or come across flawed C code which has undefined behavior, and they will naturally ask questions. A good teacher would do their best to answer, and may even anticipate questions to pre-answer. The teacher could also have been teaching the students that calling `printf` with an arg list that didn't match the format wasn't syntactically incorrect or just illustrating how stacks work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code just shows that *Turbo C* is poor at optimizing code and puts everything on the stack, while *gcc* is more aggressive and keeps it in registers or throws it away all together because these three variables have no purpose.

Anyway, calling *printf* with a pattern that requires three arguments without providing these arguments, is a mistake.

**Update:**

As an explanation: I'm assuming that *printf()* will always take its argument from the stack since it's a function with a variable argument list. Or does anybody know any other calling convention for functions like *printf()*? Futhermore, I'm assuming there's no need to put anything else on the stack as there are no other variables. So this mistaken call of *printf* will print whatever is on top of the stack in *main()*. But there might be other architectures and calling conventions where my assumpations don't hold.

Comment: Given that printf is a library function I fail to see how the compiler is able to choose which way to pass parameters to it. A calling convention was chosen when the library was compiled and the compiler must conform.

Comment: The optimization is not in the call of _printf()_ but rather in how the local variables in _main()_ are stored. The problemtic call of _printf()_ just reveals what's on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior.

With an optimizing compiler, these 3 values might be optimized out as they are not used. It will print garbage.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is undefined, meaning the compiler is free to handle the situation in any way it sees fit.  As far as the language standard is concerned, both Turbo C and gcc are doing the "right" thing.

Comment: And the programmer who wrote the code is not 'doing the "right" thing'!

Answer (score 2):

If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is wrong, but not entirely.

Variables declared within a function are by default `auto` rather than `static`.

```
int foo(void) {
    static int x;
    int y;
    auto int z;

    /* ...other code... */
}
```

This means that in the function above `y` is auto, just like z, even though the `auto` keyword is not used in its declaration.  The `auto` keyword is almost never used, by the way.  Many C (and C derivative language) programmers don't even know that `auto` is a keyword because it is used so infrequently.

Being an `auto` variable usually means that the variable is stored on the program's system stack or in registers or some mix of these.  It can be at different places at different times during the course of execution of the function, and local variables that are in registers are often pushed to the stack when another function is called.  Some local variables may even be optimized away, meaning that at some point the compiler was able to determine that a particular variable's future value was no longer needed to satisfy the input needs of the future code (or the variable doesn't change and its value is just encoded within instructions).  This complicates using debuggers on optimized code.

When you take the address of a local variable the compiler then tries to lock it down to a specific address (probably by storing it on the stack).

When most compilers look at your code they will see that the names of those local variables are not used after their declaration and may decide to just not store their values anywhere.  Even if it does store those values on the stack it may also push other values on the stack before setting up to call `printf`.  Just as the compiler does not have to keep the variables you named around it is also free to create it's own temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

In MingW-GCC: 3 garbage values.

In VC++ 2010: 0, 0, and a garbage value.